# I was raised being called "sister" by my family. What's the background on this usage?

Tags: dialects, names, kinship-terms

I was called "sister", as a replacement for my name. (Oddly, my brother was not called "brother.") I never questioned this growing up in the 50's in a rural area. It says much about the culture I grew up in. Yet I cannot explain it well, to younger people or to those not from a rural upbringing, in the 50's and prior.

This was reflective of my role in the family, not any sisterhood. A friend was confused by this, only understanding sister as in sisterhood.

I haven't been able to find any background or etymology on any website. It's simple but I'm interested in cultural aspects as well as any fiction reflecting this.

Comment: I don't really understand, but could it perhaps be related to the way nuns are called sisters amongst themselves?

Comment: So your father and mother and uncles and aunts and neighbours all called you "sister"? Interesting... what culture is this?

Comment: You say you grew up in a rural area. Did you grow up in rural Appalachia?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Though it's hard to tell without more context this sounds a lot like the nickname 'bubba' which seems to come from child-speak for 'brother'. So as strange as may sound outside, all the relatives calling her 'sister' are probably not using it as an extended kinship term but just as a common nickname.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR/DKrueger: an isolated dirt road in pristine farm country, in the most northwestern corner of the Garden State, in sight of the Delaware Water Gap; an area which is still very undeveloped. My family was Dutch & German. Only my immediate family called me sister. Our speaking accent was taken for Southern by some, especially my Mother's, who spoke in a guttural grunting tone which did sound Appalachian to me. There was a terseness and a lack of emotion and expression in our communication.

Comment: @Mitch: This was a kinship term. I'm curious as to how or why it came to be used instead of my name, though it sounded perfectly fine and normal at the time. Most relatives were born at the turn of the century, they were farmers, and were quaint lacking outside influences and education. The area today is advancing, though there are still rural pockets of extreme loveliness alongside the same degree of backwardness. Hard as that may be to believe of New Jersey.

Comment: I've heard some of my older relatives in the Ozarks (SW Missouri) refer to each other that way. I never really thought about it before.

Comment: Is is possible that you were called "sister" by your brother when he was very young (and couldn't pronounce your name yet), and the name stuck, as a nickname?

Comment: No doubt most Americans know what "The Garden State" is: those of us in the rest of the world may not (I don't, though I'm reasonably knowledgeable about US geography). Incidentally, nobody has yet made explicit mention of which country you are in!

Comment: @Colin: *Garden State* is the nickname of New Jersey (USA).

Comment: @Marthaª - ... to which George Carlin once said, "Sure, if you are growing smokestacks".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Oxford English Dictionary, there are a full eight different senses listed for *sister*.  For its use as a [vocative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case), however, they write:

> In the vocative, as a mode of address, chiefly in transferred senses. Also colloq. as a mode of address to an unrelated woman, esp. one whose name is not known.
>
> > 1943    Amer. Speech 18 88 [New Zealand English]   Sister is also used for a girl as a term of address. It is not‥a recent adoption from American films, but a relic of the whaling slang of a century ago.

The first use of *sister* as a vocative in any sense is from the 12th century:

> c1175    Lamb. Hom. 5   Leoue broðre and sustre ȝe hi-hered hu [etc.].

In the specific case of calling someone *sister* as befits their position in the family, there are no notes of when it was first used. According to the OED, *sister* was first used around 900AD. As a vocative, this meaning could have transferred at any point after 1175. I cannot read Old English, so I am unable to tell if it contains the same use of *sister* as in your case.